# How can I find relationship between two entities or words using NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am fairly new to NLP. I am finding difficulty in finding the relationship between two words. For example, *Sarah spends $10. Max Spends $100. All of them spent some amount. In total, they spent $500.*

Now, there are multiple persons spending some money, i.e., `Sarah, Max, All of them,` and `They`. And for some of them, there is an associated amount of money that they spend. I can train the NLP model to do NER and find out which represents a person and which word represents money, but how can I build a solution which tells me that `$10` is associated with `Sarah`, `$100` is associated with `Max`, `$500` is associated with `They`.

One more thing, what is this type of problem called in NLP?
I appreciate your help. It is also great if you can provide me just with the topics that I can research to explore this type of problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Machine Reading Comprehension (MRC)

[MRC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/machine-reading-comprehension/) is very popular subtask of [Natural Language Understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_understanding) (NLU).
Check the popular benchmark dataset for this task; [SQuAD](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/explore/1.1/dev/). This task is to find an answer span for the given question. For example, if the question is "How much does Sarah spend?", a model should outputs

```
Sarah spends <answer>$10</answer>. Max Spends ...
```

## Knowledge Graph Building (KGB)

You may first extract entities as node in [KG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_graph).

- `Sarah` and `Max` could be tagged as [named entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity). So, tagging them could be the problem of [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER).
- `they` is a head noun. You could find it though [Dependency Parsing](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/14.pdf).

Then you may extract the relation `spend` with a corresponding value.

```
Sarah  spend  $10
Max    spend  $100
they   spend  $500
```

In this case, the problem could be defined as [Information Extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction) or [Relation Extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_extraction).